# Trying to make factorial in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, for-loop

I'm trying to make factorial in React but I don't know what's going on and the result doesn't appear correct.

I think there is something wrong when I tried to do a for-loop. When the input value is `0`, `1` or `2`, no result appears.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';   

function Calculo_Do_Fatorial() {
    const [Dado, setdado] = useState('');
    const [resultado, setResultado] = useState();
    var fatorial = Dado;
    var primeiroMultipicador = Dado - 1;


function calcular () {

    if (Dado < 0) {
        let cheio = 'O valor de x deve ser igual ou maior que zero';
            setResultado(cheio)

    }if (Dado === 0 || Dado === 1) {
        let cheio1 = 1 ;
           setResultado(cheio1)

    }for (var i = primeiroMultipicador; i > 1; i--) {
        fatorial = fatorial*i;
   
        let cheio2 = fatorial;
            setResultado(cheio2);
    }
        
    }
  
    return (
        <div className='Calculo_Do_Fatorial'>
          <h1>Cálculo do Fatorial</h1><br></br>
          
  
              <div className="input">
                <label htmlfor="nome">Insira o número </label>
                <input type="number"  required="required" value={Dado} onChange={(e)=> setdado(e.target.value)}/>
              </div>  
                <button className="calcular1" id='calcular' onClick={calcular}>Calcular</button>
                <div className="result" id='resultado' >{typeof resultado === 'number' ? resultado.toFixed( 5 ).replaceAll(".", ",") : resultado}</div>  
        </div>
    );
}

export default Calculo_Do_Fatorial
```

I don't know what can be done to fix

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a better (in my own opinion) to name your `useState()` in a [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Such as

```
const [dado, setdado] = useState(); // And also change the initial value to empty, not empty string ('')
```

I think there are some problem in your `calcular()` function.

```
function calcular () {
    if (dado < 0) {
        let cheio = 'O valor de x deve ser igual ou maior que zero';
            setResultado(cheio)
    } else if (dado == 0 || dado == 1) {
           setResultado(1)
    } else if (dado == 2) {
        // I don't know why the for-loop doesn't work if input 2,
        // I suspect it's because the: var primeiroMultipicador = Dado - 1;
        // But I don't want change too much of the code
        // So I decided to add one more else if
        setResultado(2)
    } else {
        for (var i = primeiroMultipicador; i > 1; i--) {
            fatorial = fatorial*i;
            let cheio2 = fatorial;
                setResultado(cheio2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

1. Number inputs value type is a string, not a number, so using strict equality (`===`) with `dado < 0` and `dado === 0 || dado === 1` fails.

```js
console.log("1" === 1); // false
console.log(1 === 1);   // true
```

2. You aren't returning early for the early conditionals, so the for-loop is still processed and enqueueing further state updates when it can.

## Solution

- Return within each condition block when updating state.
- Move the `factorial` and `primeiroMultipicador` declarations into `calcular` just before the for-loop, and move the state update out of the loop.
- Update the `dado` state variable to maintain a number type invariant.

Code:

```
function CalculoDoFatorial() {
  const [dado, setdado] = useState(0); // <-- number type
  const [resultado, setResultado] = useState();

  function calcular() {
    if (dado < 0) {
      return setResultado("O valor de x deve ser igual ou maior que zero");
    }

    if (dado === 0 || dado === 1) {
      return setResultado(1);
    }

    let fatorial = dado;
    const primeiroMultipicador = dado - 1;
    for (var i = primeiroMultipicador; i > 1; i--) {
      fatorial = fatorial * i;
    }
    setResultado(fatorial);
  }

  return (
    <div className="CalculoDoFatorial">
      <h1>Cálculo do Fatorial</h1>
      <br></br>

      <div className="input">
        <label htmlfor="nome">Insira o número </label>
        <input
          type="number"
          required="required"
          value={dado}
          onChange={(e) => setdado(Number(e.target.value))} // <-- number type
        />
      </div>
      <button className="calcular1" id="calcular" onClick={calcular}>
        Calcular
      </button>
      <div className="result" id="resultado">
        {typeof resultado === "number"
          ? resultado.toFixed(5).replaceAll(".", ",")
          : resultado}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit trying-to-make-factorial-in-react]

FYI, a functional method to compute the factorial could be:

```
const factorial = [...Array(dado).keys()]
  .map((i) => i + 1)
  .reduce((factorial, i) => factorial * i, 1);

setResultado(factorial);
```

or

```
const factorial = Array.from({ length: dado }, (_, i) => i + 1)
  .reduce((factorial, i) => factorial * i, 1);

setResultado(factorial);
```

Either creates an array of [1..n] and reduces it into a factorial value. The benefit here is that you don't need to handle `0` or `1` as specific cases.

[image: Edit trying-to-make-factorial-in-react (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a well-known one-line implementation of factorial using recursion

```
const factorial = n => n === 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1)
```